# how to compare two dates with ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I would like to compare two dates directly in the html component, with ngIf

I tried with this code, but it didn't work,

I wanted when today's date was greater than the vPromoData date not to show the contents of my div

```
<div *ngIf=" item.tabela.vPromo && today < item.tabela.vPromoData " >{{item.tabela.vPromoData | json}}</div>


  public today = new Date();


  "tabela": {
  "itemTabela_id": 2,
  "item_id": 7650,
  "vVenda": 95.9,
  "vPromo": 77.5,
  "vPromoData": "2022-09-25"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get `yyyy-MM-dd` from Date object from `toISOString` and chopping the unnecessary part, sth along the lines

```js
const todayAsString = new Date().toISOString().split('T').shift(); 
console.log(todayAsString);
```

But: Angular has a built-in pipe, `date`, for formatting dates. Just use it in the template

```
<div *ngIf="item.tabela.vPromo && (today | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd') < item.tabela.vPromoData">
```

Comment: Cool, instead of today would I use todayAsString?

Comment: can ngIf compare dates in this mode? 2022-10-18 >= 2022-10-16

Answer (score 0):

Use the timestamps of each date.

You can get it with `yourDate.getTime()`, it returns a number that you can then compare.

```js
const date = new Date();

const now = Date.now();
const yesterday = date.setHours(-24);

console.log(now);
console.log(yesterday);

console.log(now > yesterday);
```

## EDIT

With string date-likes

```js
const date = '2022-10-18';

const now = new Date(...date.split('-')).getTime();
const yesterday = new Date(...date.split('-')).setHours(-24);

console.log(now);
console.log(yesterday);

console.log(now > yesterday);
```

Comment: I think this code can't solve the problem, I need to compare the dates according to the json I get and by ngIf

Comment: I get the date in the format 2022-09-25

Comment: Well it was implied you had to create date objects ...

Answer (score 0):

As you has the date in format yyyy-MM-dd you can compare "string", the only is convert to string "today"

```
dateToString(date:any)
{
  return date.getFullYear()+'-'+
         ('00'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'
         ('00'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)
}

//And use 

todayTxt:string=this.dateToString(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with dates use some well tested and robust library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) that is tree-shakeable, supports locales and works with built-in Date objects too.

```
isAfter(
  parse(item.tabela.vPromoData, 'yyyy-MM-dd', new Date()), 
  new Date()
)
```